# trying to configure apache for ssl

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I have Apache 2.4.6 installed on RHEL 7 and it works fine without SSL. Since I am doing this for the first time, I have few questions:

The [doc here says](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) that my SSL Configuration (which I believe`httpd.conf`) must contain the following entries:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have searched my `httpd.conf` for the lines `<VirtualHost>` and `LoadModule` but couldn't find it. I was under assumption that they might have commented out and I would need to uncomment it and make changes but both the lines doesnt' exist.

1) Can I copy and paste above two entries at the end of my file and configure or is it an abnormal thing that I didn't see above things commented out?

2) From where I can figure out if I have `mod_ssl.so` present somewhere in my Apache or not?

3) Right now, my listen is defined as follows :`Listen XX.XX.XXX.XX:80`where `XX.XX.XXX.XX` is my server IP address. Should I comment it out and completely change it to `XX.XX.XXX.XX:443` ? The documentation just says `Listen 443` and hence I am confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1>
You *can* simply append to your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but it might be a better idea to have the configuration for this specific virtualhost in its own configuration file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.ssl.conf` or `/etc/httpd/sites-available` (with a corresponding symlink in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`), depending upon how your system's Apache configuration paradigm is laid out (former is RHEL; latter is Debian).

2>
The simplest way is a simple `grep` (`grep -R '[^#]*mod_ssl\.so' /etc/httpd/*` to find any non-commented-out reference to that module, for instance.

3>
From the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen):

> **Listen Directive**
>
> Description:  IP addresses and ports that the server listens to
>
> Syntax:   `Listen [IP-address:]portnumber [protocol]`
>
> The Listen directive instructs Apache httpd to listen to only
>   specific IP addresses or ports; by default it responds to requests on
>   all IP interfaces. Listen is now a required directive. If it is not in
>   the config file, the server will fail to start. This is a change from
>   previous versions of Apache httpd.
>
> The Listen directive tells the server to accept incoming requests on
>   the specified port or address-and-port combination. If only a port
>   number is specified, the server listens to the given port on all
>   interfaces. If an IP address is given as well as a port, the server
>   will listen on the given port and interface.

If you say `Listen 443`, Apache will heed all HTTP requests on all interfaces; if you say `Listen 10.11.12.13:443`, it will only listen for HTTPS requests on the network interface bound to the IP address 10.11.12.13.

Comment: CentOS and thus I believe RH supplies the default SSL config in `conf.d/ssl.conf`.from package `mod_ssl` -- and if that package isn't installed this won't work at all.